# Which versions are required to get a working Acceleo Maven build

Tags: acceleo

Has anyone got the Acceleo Maven build to work?

If so what combination of Maven, Tycho, Eclipse, Acceleo, UML2/ecore worked for you?

And as a supplementary question do you still need to adjust the Java classes and config files before running the build (as was required for the old ANT build)?

To be clearer tycho does not like Maven 3.3, Maven 3.3 is the default with Luna. Every version of Eclipse has a different version of the ecore/uml model built in so migrating the Acceleo templates to another version of eclipse requires changes in all "module" definitions and hacking the version inside the UML models, so, its tedious trying to work out which versions are compatible.

I just wondered if someone had a working setup where all the components worked together.

After much trial and error:-

```
 Eclipse Luna
        Comes with Eclipse m2e 1.5
        ecore uml2  version 5.0.2
 Acceleo 3.5.1
 Maven 3.0.5
 org.eclipse.acceleo:org.eclipse.acceleo.maven:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT
```

All work together without the usual class not found and missing jars.
However I have yet to build a working pom that actually generates some 
template output.

Interestingly the ANT build seems to work fine.

In the end it was just easier to knock up a .bat script to run
the generate and build.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [UML to Java generator](https://git.eclipse.org/c/umlgen/org.eclipse.umlgen.git/tree/org.eclipse.umlgen.gen.java/plugins/org.eclipse.umlgen.gen.java/pom.xml) of the Eclipse Foundation for the configuration of the pom.xml. For additional information on the use of maven with Acceleo, look at the [dedicated page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Maven) on the wiki.

You do not need to modify any Java class or configuration file now.

Comment: Why would a pom from another project help? Acceleo builds a pom file etc. Does it build an invalid pom.